# Why pointer returns value and not address?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c-str

This code:

```
string  str1 ( "Hello world" );
const char *c_str1 = str1.c_str ( );
cout << "The C-style string c_str1 is: " << c_str1
```

generates this output:

```
The C-style string c_str1 is: Hello world
```

and I do not understand it.

`c_str1` is a pointer, right? So, `c_str1` should return an address and only `*c_str1` should give the value located at this address. However, in the above example `c_str1` gives the value (not the address).

What do I misunderstand?

Comment: `&c_str1` would be the address of the pointer. You were thinking of `*c_str1`, except that that would give you the first `char` only.

Comment: @larsmans, I thought that `&x` gives address of normal variable `x` and "address of pointer" is something strange since pointer is already an address.

Comment: Simplifying just a little bit, a pointer to `T` is a variable containing an address. That variable must live somewhere, so it too has an address, which is of type `T**` (pointer to pointer to `T`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of how `std::cout::operator <<` is defined - it has an overload that takes a `const char*` and prints the string it points to. If you want the address, you'll have to cast to `void*`.

Comment: I'd say "specified", not "implemented".  It's implemented this way because that is how the standard specifies it.

Answer (score 4):

"What do I misunderstand?"  The definition of `<<` on a `char
const*`.  The pointer is passed by value, but the definition of
`operator<<( std::ostream&, char const* )` specifies that it
treat the pointer as the start of a `'\0'` terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `c_str1` is a pointer to the first character in the string. `&c_str1` is a pointer to `c_str1` (i.e. a pointer to a pointer). `*c_str1` is the value at the location pointed to by `c_str1` (i.e. only a single character).

The output operator has an overload that takes a pointer to a character (what `c_str1` is) and prints it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [overload of `ostream& operator<<` for `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), which assumes the pointer points to the first character in a [null terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), and prints the whole string.

You can see an example of this assumption being applied somewhere it shouldn't here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char c = 'x'; // not a null terminated string
  std::cout << &c << std::endl; // will write until it finds a 0 (really UB)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard specifies overloads of `operator<< (ostream, char*)` which output the string stored in the pointer. In other words, `c_str1` is indeed a pointer, but the output stream is interpreting it as the string it points to.

To output the pointer value, cast it to `void*`:

```
cout << "The C-style string c_str1 is: " << static_cast<void*>(c_str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cout operator<< interprets pointers to char as C-strings.